# Keepass client on Android (reliable one)

Tags: passwords, password-management

I need some advice to choose a Keepass client on Android phone which can synchronize using Dropbox.

As i keep all my passwords in one place, I would like to keep it safe. Is KeepassDroid client safe to use on mobile phones? Any bad experiences by using such a client?

Comment: Is KeePassDroid safe to use? I know that earlier versions stored decrypted passwords on the device. The author's justification for doing this seemed unconvincing.

Comment: Looks like https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/keepassdroid-discuss/MrDVby5MkFQ is the topic of discussion regarding Keepass encryption on Droid.

Answer (score 4):

I've been very happy with KeePassDroid and it does happily sync via dropbox on your android phone. Check out their blog http://blog.keepassdroid.com/2010/06/dropbox-and-keepassdroid.html

keepassdroid is very popular and open source so you are welcome to take a look through the source code. https://github.com/bpellin/keepassdroid

The main thing to keep in mind with keepass is make sure you have that keepass file protected with a strong password!

Answer (score 2):

I've been using [Keepass2Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=keepass2android.keepass2android) for a number of years without any problems. I use it to synchronise to Dropbox where my `.kdbx` file is stored. But it can also use Google Drive, SkyDrive, FTP and WebDAV.

Note that it caches a local copy of the `.kdbx` file so can work offline.

Keepass2Android is also open source:
https://github.com/PhilippC/keepass2android